# Help me solve problems in my class schedule table

Tags: tables, diagbox

I'd like to make a class schedule.

I have written the following, which is partly adapted from an example given by someone else.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[11.5pt]{9.5pt}
\usepackage{ctex}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{ulem}


\title{xxx}
\author{xx}
\date{2022}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
{\centering\sffamily\large\@date\hfil\@title\hfil\@author\par}
\vskip1ex}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\timeslot}[2]{\makecell*{#1\\#2}}
\newcommand{\class}[3][]{\makecell{#2\\[-1ex]{\hfill\scriptsize#3}}}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\Mandarin{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\MandarinX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Mathematics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\MathematicsX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\English{\class{xx}{xx}}
\newcommand\EnglishX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Physics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysicsX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysicsXX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Chemistry{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\ChemistryX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Geography{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysEd{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysEdX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Society{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Labour{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\History{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Politics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Psychology{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Art{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Biology{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Assembly{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\IT{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Recess{\multirow{7}{*}[-2.75ex]{\makecell{x\\x\\[1em]B\\R\\E\\A\\K}}}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\HNtimetable}

\savebox{\HNtimetable}{\parbox{\textwidth}{
\maketitle
\centering
\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width1.2pt}c!{\vrule width1.2pt}c|c|c|c!{\vrule width1.2pt}c!{\vrule width1.2pt}c|c|c|c|c|c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}
\Xhline{1.2pt}
Lesson & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 && 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\Cline{0.8pt}{1-5}
\Cline{0.8pt}{7-12}
\diagbox{\footnotesize x}{\footnotesize x}
& 
\timeslot{08:00}{08:40} &
\timeslot{08:50}{09:30} &
\timeslot{09:45}{10:25} &
\timeslot{10:35}{11:15} &
\Recess &
\timeslot{12:40}{13:20} &
\timeslot{13:30}{14:10} &
\timeslot{14:25}{15:05} &
\timeslot{15:15}{15:55} &
\timeslot{16:05}{16:45} &
\timeslot{16:55}{17:35} \\
\Cline{1.2pt}{1-5}
\Cline{1.2pt}{7-12}
Mon &
\Mathematics &
\Mandarin &
\Chemistry &
\PhysEd &
&
\EnglishX &
\Biology &
\Physics &
\PhysicsXX &
\Society &
&
\\
\cline{1-5}
\cline{7-12}
Tue &
\EnglishX &
\Geography &
\Mathematics &
\Labour &
&
\History &
\Art &
\Politics &
\Mandarin &
&
&
\\
\cline{1-5}
\cline{7-12}

Wed &
\Mathematics&
\Chemistry &
\English &
\Psychology &
&
\Mandarin &
\PhysEdX &
\PhysEdX &
\Biology &
\Physics &
&
&
\\
\cline{1-5}
\cline{7-12}

Thu &
\IT &
\IT &
\MandarinX &
\English &
&
\PhysEd &
\Geography &
\Mathematics &
\Labour &
&
&
\\
\cline{1-5}
\cline{7-12}

Fri &
\PhysicsX &
\History &
\MathematicsX &
\ChemistryX &
&
\Politics &
\English &
\MandarinX &
\Assembly &
&
&
\\
\Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabular}
}}


\noindent\usebox{\HNtimetable}

\end{document}
```

However, when I personalised it, there were some problems that made the form not so perfect. I suggest you run this code on OverLeaf as it throws some exceptions and OverLeaf can handle them.
[image]

Now I want to improve 3 aspects:

1. As you can see, there are huge cracks in the last few rows of the table. How do you fix them?
2. I used the `diagbox`, but it did not fit the top corners of the frame perfectly.
3. The Cline command I used didn't work very well. It could not customize the thickness of the line, even though I had passed in the parameters.

Comment: Please specify errors here. Also, "Overleaf can handle them" is an illusion. LaTeX isn't made to produce correct output while there are errors. Overleaf is just configured to ignore errors and produce random output when that happens. The first advice you'll get is: fix the errors and then ask your question about what you don't like with the result.

Comment: @Miyase You are right, but these exceptions are mainly about the command `\Oldarrayrulewidth `, which I'm not really capable of fixing. How would you fix the command?

Comment: Please attach screenshots, which show your layout (?) problems. Not everybody is willing to run code posted here just to see, what's wrong. While, once visible, it can be identified many times by this community right away. // And, at least I'm not interested to install (old) packages which I will never need again, just to "have a look". // Why don't you use more recent packages, like schedule or so? https://www.ctan.org/topic/timetable // https://www.ctan.org/topic/planning

Comment: @MS-SPO A screenshot is attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment adds functionalities to the classical `{tabular}`. In particular, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the built-in command `\Block`. With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn except in the blocks (created by `\Block`). That's what I have used in the following code.

For the heavy rules, I have drawn them with Tikz after the construction of the array. Indeed, `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the rows, columns and cells of the array. It's possible to use those nodes with Tikz to draw whatever rule you want after the construction of the tabular.

That's what I have done with

```
  \tikz \draw [very thick] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) 
                           (1-|6) -- (last-|6) 
                           (1-|7) -- (last-|7) ;
```

Eventually, the environment `{NiceTabular}` has its built-in command `\diagbox` which always gives a perfect result (because the diagonal rule is drawn with Tikz).

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\changefontsizes[11.5pt]{9.5pt}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\timeslot}[2]{\makecell{#1\\#2}}

\newcommand{\class}[3][]{\makecell{#2\\[-1ex]{\hfill\scriptsize#3}}}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\Mandarin{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\MandarinX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Mathematics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\MathematicsX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\English{\class{xx}{xx}}
\newcommand\EnglishX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Physics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysicsX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysicsXX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Chemistry{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\ChemistryX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Geography{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysEd{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysEdX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Society{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Labour{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\History{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Politics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Psychology{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Art{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Biology{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Assembly{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\IT{\class{xx}{xxx}}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccccccccc}[hvlines]
Lesson & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \Block{*-1}{x\\x\\ \\ B\\R\\E\\A\\K} & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\diagbox{\footnotesize\; x\strut}{\footnotesize x\strut\;}
& 
\timeslot{08:00}{08:40} &
\timeslot{08:50}{09:30} &
\timeslot{09:45}{10:25} &
\timeslot{10:35}{11:15} & & 
\timeslot{12:40}{13:20} &
\timeslot{13:30}{14:10} &
\timeslot{14:25}{15:05} &
\timeslot{15:15}{15:55} &
\timeslot{16:05}{16:45} &
\timeslot{16:55}{17:35} \\
Mon &
\Mathematics &
\Mandarin &
\Chemistry &
\PhysEd &
&
\EnglishX &
\Biology &
\Physics &
\PhysicsXX &
\Society &
\\
Tue &
\EnglishX &
\Geography &
\Mathematics &
\Labour &
&
\History &
\Art &
\Politics &
\Mandarin &
&
\\
Wed &
\Mathematics&
\Chemistry &
\English &
\Psychology &
&
\Mandarin &
\PhysEdX &
\PhysEdX &
\Biology &
\Physics &
\\
Thu &
\IT &
\IT &
\MandarinX &
\English &
&
\PhysEd &
\Geography &
\Mathematics &
\Labour &
&
\\
Fri &
\PhysicsX &
\History &
\MathematicsX &
\ChemistryX &
&
\Politics &
\English &
\MandarinX &
\Assembly &
&
\\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [very thick] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) 
                           (1-|6) -- (last-|6) 
                           (1-|7) -- (last-|7) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes used by `nicematrix`.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: How do I draw horizontal thick lines? Not very familiar with TikZ, sorry.

Comment: `(i-|j)` is the node at the intersection of the (potential) line `i` and column `j`. So, if you use `\tikz \draw (i-|1) -- (i-|last) ; ` you draw a horizontal rule on the line number `i`.

Comment: Many thanks! You solve my problem perfectly.

Comment: Usually, in TeX SE, people provide MWE (minimal working example). Your problem of tabular has nothing to do with the title. In order to have a shorter answer, I have deleted the instructions which are not linked to the tabular. You won't have difficulties to put them again in your final document :-)

Comment: I see. It's very impressive to fully understand the concept of MWE now.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have to define `\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}`
2. There are a couple of rows that have one or two `&` too much.

Here is a corrected version

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[11.5pt]{9.5pt}
\usepackage{ctex}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{ulem}


\title{xxx}
\author{xx}
\date{2022}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
{\centering\sffamily\large\@date\hfil\@title\hfil\@author\par}
\vskip1ex}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\timeslot}[2]{\makecell*{#1\\#2}}
\newcommand{\class}[3][]{\makecell{#2\\[-1ex]{\hfill\scriptsize#3}}}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\Mandarin{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\MandarinX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Mathematics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\MathematicsX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\English{\class{xx}{xx}}
\newcommand\EnglishX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Physics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysicsX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysicsXX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Chemistry{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\ChemistryX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Geography{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysEd{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\PhysEdX{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Society{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Labour{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\History{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Politics{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Psychology{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Art{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Biology{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Assembly{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\IT{\class{xx}{xxx}}
\newcommand\Recess{\multirow{7}{*}[-2.75ex]{\makecell{x\\x\\[1em]B\\R\\E\\A\\K}}}
\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\HNtimetable}

\savebox{\HNtimetable}{\parbox{\textwidth}{
\maketitle
\centering
\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width1.2pt}c!{\vrule width1.2pt}c|c|c|c!{\vrule width1.2pt}c!{\vrule width1.2pt}c|c|c|c|c|c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}
\Xhline{1.2pt}
Lesson & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 && 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\Cline{0.8pt}{1-5}
\Cline{0.8pt}{7-12}
\diagbox{\footnotesize x}{\footnotesize x}
& 
\timeslot{08:00}{08:40} &
\timeslot{08:50}{09:30} &
\timeslot{09:45}{10:25} &
\timeslot{10:35}{11:15} &
\Recess &
\timeslot{12:40}{13:20} &
\timeslot{13:30}{14:10} &
\timeslot{14:25}{15:05} &
\timeslot{15:15}{15:55} &
\timeslot{16:05}{16:45} &
\timeslot{16:55}{17:35} \\
\Cline{1.2pt}{1-5}
\Cline{1.2pt}{7-12}
Mon &
\Mathematics &
\Mandarin &
\Chemistry &
\PhysEd &
&
\EnglishX &
\Biology &
\Physics &
\PhysicsXX &
\Society &
\\
\cline{1-5}
\cline{7-12}
Tue &
\EnglishX &
\Geography &
\Mathematics &
\Labour &
&
\History &
\Art &
\Politics &
\Mandarin &
&
\\
\cline{1-5}
\cline{7-12}

Wed &
\Mathematics&
\Chemistry &
\English &
\Psychology &
&
\Mandarin &
\PhysEdX &
\PhysEdX &
\Biology &
\Physics &
\\
\cline{1-5}
\cline{7-12}

Thu &
\IT &
\IT &
\MandarinX &
\English &
&
\PhysEd &
\Geography &
\Mathematics &
\Labour &
&
\\
\cline{1-5}
\cline{7-12}

Fri &
\PhysicsX &
\History &
\MathematicsX &
\ChemistryX &
&
\Politics &
\English &
\MandarinX &
\Assembly &
&
\\
\Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabular}
}}


\noindent\usebox{\HNtimetable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for solving the first question. But `\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}` doesn't actually solve it. Also the `diagbox` problem is still unfixed.